# Generating mesh along path

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, mesh

I'm currently trying to generate a path along an array of points (Vector3)
This is the result I'm currently getting:

- **The dark gray points are the given path**
- **The red points are the generated vertices**
- **And the triangles are obviously the mesh I failed to generate correctly**

[image]

And from the bottom it looks like this, which is odd, because I'd expect all the missing triangles to be at the bottom. But some of them just don't exist:

[image]
here's the code i wrote that generates the path mesh

```
//Removed code since there's no need in showing something that doesn't work
```

And here's a quick example of what it looks like when I drag a path:

[image]

SOLUTION FOUND

As the accepted answer states, I was skipping triangles in my triangle for loop.
Here is my new working code:

```
public static Mesh extrudeAlongPath(Vector3[] points, float width){
    if (points.Length < 2)
        return null;
    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    List<Vector3> verts = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> norms = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++) {
        if(i != points.Length-1){
            Vector3 perpendicularDirection = new Vector3(-( points[i+1].z-points[i].z ), points[i].y, points[i+1].x -points[i].x).normalized;
            verts.Add (points[i]+perpendicularDirection*width);
            norms.Add (Vector3.up);
            verts.Add (points[i]+perpendicularDirection*-width);
            norms.Add (Vector3.up);
        }else{
            Vector3 perpendicularDirection = new Vector3(-( points[i].z-points[i-1].z ), points[i].y, points[i].x -points[i-1].x).normalized;
            verts.Add (points[i]+perpendicularDirection*-width);
            norms.Add (Vector3.up);
            verts.Add (points[i]+perpendicularDirection*width);
            norms.Add (Vector3.up);
        }
    }
    m.vertices = verts.ToArray ();
    m.normals = norms.ToArray ();

    List<int> tris = new List<int> ();
    //Changed i+=3 to i++
    for(int i = 0; i < m.vertices.Length-3; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
        tris.Add(i+2);
        tris.Add(i+1);
        tris.Add(i);
        }else{
            tris.Add(i);
            tris.Add(i+1);
            tris.Add(i+2);
        }
    }
    m.triangles = tris.ToArray ();

    m.name = "pathMesh";
    m.RecalculateNormals ();
    m.RecalculateBounds ();
    m.Optimize ();
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Does anything chance when you remove `m.RecalculateNormals ();` or `m.RecalculateBounds ();`?

Comment: unfortunately not, the exact same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the tris for loop to ++ instead of +=3:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m.vertices.Length-3; i++){
    tris.Add(i+2);
    tris.Add(i+1);
    tris.Add(i);
}
```

Each 2 neighboring triangles have 2 shared vertices, so += 3 would skip 2 triangles each time.

Comment: That definitely did something !
http://i.imgur.com/C5reRc6.png

Comment: but how would i get those odd triangles to face upwards?

Comment: I have to go to work now, but i'll check back in my break in about 3 hours or so :)
thanks for helping me!

Comment: I figured it out, added it to question